# Slider Counter Not Incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My slider is allowing for  content to go forwards and backwards when the Next/Previous links are clicked. When I switch the contentType to 'div' it only shows content in slides 1 and 3. Could someone please explain why the counter is not incrementing properly? Is there a more effecient way to do this? I have included my code below as well as a working example. The purpose of this script is to allow for images or content to be displayed in a slide. Any help is much appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
  var $el = $('#showcase');
  var $leftArrow = $('#left_arrow');
  var $rightArrow = $('#right_arrow');
  var contentType = $('div'); // change to img and reverse comment out HTML code
  var slideCount = $el.children().length;
  var slideNum = 1;
  var $load = $el.find(contentType)[0];

  // PRELOADS SLIDE WITH CORRECT SETTINGS
  $load.className = 'active';
  $leftArrow.addClass("disabled");

  // CHECKS FOR FIRST AND LAST INDEX
  function checkSlide() {
    if (slideNum == 1) {
      $leftArrow.addClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $leftArrow.removeClass('disabled');
    }

    if (slideNum == slideCount) {
      $rightArrow.addClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $rightArrow.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  }

  // NAVIGATIONAL LOGIC FOR PREVIOUS/NEXT BUTTONS
  $leftArrow.click(function() {
    if (slideNum > 1) {
      var counter = $(".active").index();
      counter--;
      $('.active').addClass('slide');
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      contentType.eq(counter).addClass('active');
      slideNum--;
      checkSlide();
      console.log('slideNum: ' + slideNum);
      console.log('counter: ' + counter);
    }
  })

  $rightArrow.click(function() {
    if (slideNum < slideCount) {
      var counter = $(".active").index();
      counter++;
      $('.active').addClass('slide');
      $(".active").removeClass('active');
      contentType.eq(counter).addClass('active');
      slideNum++;
      checkSlide();
      console.log('slideNum: ' + slideNum);
      console.log('counter: ' + counter);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 160px;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

.disabled {
  color: red !important;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <div id="showcase">
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=306" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=626" />
</div>
<a href="#" id="left_arrow">&laquo; Previous</a>
<a href="#" id="right_arrow">Next &raquo;</a> -->


<div id="showcase">
  <div class="slide">Page 1 content</div>
  <div class="slide">Page 2 content</div>
  <div class="slide">Page 3 content</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="left_arrow">&laquo; Previous</a>
<a href="#" id="right_arrow">Next &raquo;</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your "contentType" var, which matches divs, also matches the "showcase" div, so you are getting 4 in your list, not 3 as you expect. In your left/right arrow click handlers, replace:

```
contentType.eq(counter).addClass('active');
```

with:

```
$el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris. This solved the issue I was experiencing. Just to clarify for others, "contentType" was registering the "showcase" div along with my "slide" divs. I needed to drill down to the "slide" divs so the script could target those alone by adding "$el.find".